# Fullcalendar RRule recurring events - renders wrong end date in timeGridWeek

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, rrule

the two events **Event A** and **Event B** in actual data do not overlap in timings:

```
Event A:- start:2021-03-01T01:20:00.000Z, end: 2021-03-01T02:00:00.000Z

Event B:- start:2021-03-01T02:00:00.000Z, end: 2021-03-01T02:20:00.000Z
```

But this is how they appear on the calendar:

[image: two events overlapping but not in actual]

Event definitions:

```
events: [
  {
    id: 762,
    title: "Event A",
    start: "2021-03-01T01:20:00.000Z",
    end: "2021-03-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    allDay: false,
    eventColor: "#36BFD7",
    color: "#F05974",
    labelName: "TIK",
    rrule: {
      freq: "weekly",
      interval: 1,
      dtstart: "2021-03-01T01:20:00.000Z",
      until: "2021-04-08",
      byweekday: ["Mo"],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 763,
    title: "Event B",
    start: "2021-03-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2021-03-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    allDay: false,
    eventColor: "#36BFD7",
    color: "#9E69AF",
    labelName: "PPKN",
    rrule: {
      freq: "weekly",
      interval: 1,
      dtstart: "2021-03-01T02:00:00.000Z",
      until: "2021-04-08",
      byweekday: ["Mo"],
    },
  },
],
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/abdul007malik/pen/rNjxRwP

Comment: YES, timezone is in utc

Comment: @ZiaurRehman no it's nothing to do with timezone. Not sure how you came to that conclusion - would you like to explain your logic? All the events have the same timezone (UTC), and are displayed on the screen at exactly the start times shown in the data. It's the end times which OP is confused about.

Comment: @ZiaurRehman Hm...there is nothing different about the new version of the question, I simply changed it to make it on-topic (by bringing in information from the CodePen which needs to be preserved here). There's no _new_ information compared to before. It was just as clear in the original version that the timezone was irrelevant. I think you just misunderstood the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an `rrule` in a fullCalendar event, the normal `start` and `end` properties of the event are ignored (because they don't make sense any more - the event no longer has a single start or end time, instead it has a recurring pattern of times).

You need to specify a `duration` value for the event - as described in the [RRule plugin documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin), otherwise fullCalendar will give the event the [default duration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultTimedEventDuration) of 1 hour. You may have noticed that your event B was too long as well? That's due to the same issue.

These definitions will produce the desired output:

```
events: [
  {
    id: 762,
    title: "Event A",
    allDay: false,
    eventColor: "#36BFD7",
    color: "#F05974",
    labelName: "TIK",
    duration: "00:40",
    rrule: {
      freq: "weekly",
      interval: 1,
      dtstart: "2021-03-01T01:20:00.000Z",
      until: "2021-04-08",
      byweekday: ["Mo"],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 763,
    title: "Event B",
    allDay: false,
    eventColor: "#36BFD7",
    color: "#9E69AF",
    labelName: "PPKN",
    duration: "00:20",
    rrule: {
      freq: "weekly",
      interval: 1,
      dtstart: "2021-03-01T02:00:00.000Z",
      until: "2021-04-08",
      byweekday: ["Mo"],
    },
  },
],
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/Bapjgdd

Comment: thanks @ADyson I am able to acheive my task after adding duration